# On finite quotients of unions of $n$ affine varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, group-actions

Assume that a finite group $G$ acts on a quasi-projective variety $Q$ (say, over complex numbers) that possesses a Zariski cover by $\le n$ affine varieties. My question is: does the quotient $Q/G$ admits a cover by  $\le n$ affine varieties also? This fact seems to be well-known in the case $n=1$; certainly, in the general case the problem is to deal with non-$G$-stable covers.